# Module[Monitor[ ... ]] doesn't work when called by Manipulate?

Tags: manipulate, scoping, display, monitoring

My example function

`progressFunction[time_] := 
 Module[{t}, 
  Monitor[For[t = 0, t <= time, t++, Pause[1]], 
   ProgressIndicator[t, {0, time}]]]`

does exactly what I intend when I call it directly:

`progressFunction[5]`

(displays progress bar increasing from 0% to 100% over 5 seconds).

But when this function is called from within Manipulate:

`Manipulate[progressFunction[time], {time}]`

the Monitor cell displays:

[image: Error]

Interestingly, when I copy/paste the above text into a new cell, it displays correctly in the new cell.

Any idea what's going on and how to fix this? This is pretty annoying because my real Manipulate expression calls functions that take a long time to complete, so I have implemented Monitor on all of them, but they all become useless under Manipulate.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly how you want the interface.  Here's way to monitor the progress but without `Monitor`:

```
ClearAll[progressFunction];
progressFunction[time_, t_] := Module[{},
   If[time > 0,
    For[t = 0, t <= time, t++, Pause[1]]
    ];
   t = 0;
   ];

Manipulate[
 progressFunction[time, Unevaluated@progress];
 {time, progress},
 {{time, 0}, InputField},
 {{progress, progress}, 0, time,
  Replace[Hold[##], 
    Hold[Dynamic[p_], i__] :> Dynamic@ProgressIndicator[p, i]] &},
 TrackedSymbols :> {time}]
```

[image]

Here's a way using `Monitor` but it's not as good since it evaluates twice.  I cannot be sure whether that would happen in your actual use case, though.

```
ClearAll[progressFunction];
progressFunction[time_, t_] :=
  Monitor[
   For[t = 0, t <= time, t++, Pause[1]],
   ProgressIndicator[t, {0, time}]
   ];

Manipulate[
 progressFunction[time, Unevaluated@timer];
 {time, timer},
 {time, InputField}, {{timer, timer}, None},
 TrackedSymbols :> {time}]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, my true analog of `progressFunction` involves several other calls to several other functions, many of which use `Monitor`. Some monitor variables in `For` loops, while others monitor variables in `FindMinimum`. They also all use the trick `f[x_]:=f[x]=...`, which gets ruined when the extra `Unevaluated@variable` parameters are used.

Comment: In short, I tried to implement these solutions in my code but they didn't work, and I think making them work would require some pretty drastic changes to my code structure.

Comment: @WillG I guess the problem is that your question didn't have some important details.

Comment: I just thought there would be a simple fix that wouldn't require significantly changing my existing code. I just need the `Monitor` cells to display the way they're supposed to, after all.